# How can I get data from an external web page into CRM 2011?

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, client-side, crm

I have to create a webpage that has simple data input that will need to be inserted into specific CRM 2011 entities. But the webpage will be on a separate system. In other words, the webpage will be located on some other machine on the internet. Upon submission, the page will need to connect to a CRM 2011 machine somewhere else on the internet and push the data entered on the form into the appropriate entity location in that remote CRM app.

This ultimately needs to be a completely client-based solution using only HTML & JavaScript/jQuery.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this like a website lead form?  On submit: create an entity "row" behind the scenes?  CRM Online or On-Premise?

Comment: I'd love examples in both just in case. I'm assuming the worst right now but will find out details soon.

Answer (score 1):

### Online

I can really only comment from experience with On-Premise.  I found some evidence that CRM Online has this baked in specifically for Leads.  OP isn't clear on what entity -- perhaps this has/can be expanded.  I'll leave the rest of the Online options to those with more experience.

### On-Premise:

The OP mentions working with a constraint of client-side only tech. I've seen a couple ways this can be done.  The main battle is crossing network boundaries. Another answer suggests the use of a webservice to expedite/simplify the data transfer.  I've written my response assuming this option is off the table -- though it would be preferred if it was not.

1. If money isn't an object,there are services that do this.  Like mail-sender form services these tools let you design/brand a form, it gets hosted with them, and when someone fills it out there is an installed integration to "get" the form submission.  Upside: you're done in no time.  Downside: you lose control of content, hosting location, it costs money.  Usually it doesn't matter if CRM is an Internet Facing Deployment (IFD) or not.
   I've heard [Scribe](http://www.scribesoft.com/CRM-Integration) is good, but I've never used them, and I do not work for them.
2. If the CRM Server is not IFD, a form could be designed to send mail.  This mail message can be processed by a queue on your CRM Server.  Many CMS tools offer these forms as an option, and there are services that provide this as well.  Major drawback to the email-queue technique is that you wind up processing mail and likely creating workflow extensions to parse out the details of the mail to the entity of choice. But transport (assuming email security is appropriate) is not a concern.
3. If neither of these are attractive and you want to own your form, host it where you want and not have to write a bunch of string processing extensions -- you could post right to the OData / REST endpoint.  As long as network accessibility of the CRM Server is available (either because its an IFD, or appropriate traffic filtering allows ingress through a firewall to it) your form could craft an appropriate JSON or XML payload to create entity rows.  Just be wary of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  This can be overcome with [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)and ["opting in"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) the CRM Server to accept cross origin posts.
4. Slight twist on the above: Also consider if the CRM Server is an IFD, you could create your form, add it to CRM as a webresource and point directly to that page.  You'll sidestep any Same Origin Policy restrictions.  Between the form submission and the REST endpoint.  You could presumably IFRAME in this form into an external site.

Some oData/REST endpoint links:
[Sample: Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete Using the REST Endpoint with JavaScript and jQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx)
[CRM 2011 JQuery OData REST Endpoints Create Record](http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.com/2011/09/crm-2011-jquery-odata-rest-endpoints.html)

Comment: #4 is actually the very route I've been looking at. Authentication/Authorization is one point of interest I'm attempting to grok through. Looks like your IFD suggestion may be at least part of the key. I'll check out the link you've given. If you have any other suggestions, especially code snips, that you could pass along, I'm all ears.

Comment: ... and I'm not the best source for notes on Internet Facing deployments.  Forms Auth is probably in play.   I think you will find that unless the submitter is preauthenticated to CRM, the requests will fail.   I've not found a way to provide authentication (other than Windows Live accounts to CRM Online) to external uses of the REST service.

Comment: Yea, that's the only caveat. I need to be able to send credentials through that WebForm that'll do everything in the background so the user doesn't even see the Windows Live challenge. If I can setup role-based security that only has access to those particular Web Resources, then I think it would work *if* I can authenticate automagically.

Comment: You may want to consider this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980080/how-to-go-pass-windows-live-authentication-and-consume-crm-odata-services/6999728#6999728).  There's also this [link] (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2011/02/04/connecting-to-crm-online-2011-web-services-using-soap-requests-only.aspx) that talks about how to access the Online webservices via SOAP.  Maybe some of that can transfer to what you are doing?

Comment: Also, you say that it must all be client side.  Would you consider going through an intermediary service?  Amazon SQS or SNS as a message bus?  Pull messages on the CRM side?  Or you could ask SNS to POST to a custom webservice on the CRM box.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of data entered/transferred, you might want to go with oData and use REST to communicate with the CRM server.

However, IMHO, a more reliable and professional approach would be creating a web service that serves the data collected. Then, you'd let CRM fetch it at its convenience.

This might seem as a worse solution at first considering that you're losing the *pushing* the data. However, you need to be concern about firewalls. Especially if you don't know the setup at the organization(s) you're targeting (extra especially if they're security conscious).

Also, depending on the details of your assignment, you might want to design an IFRAME that takes points to an external resource and does some magic. Technically, you'll be outside CRM then, while still being inside considering the GUI.

I don't have enough information to advise further at the moment.